# SelectedDateChanged is not working on Dynamic DatePicker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rad-controls, raddatepicker

I have a Dynamic DatePicker and i want call SelectedDateChanged  event but its not working/firing?? Although i have used same code on a sample applicaion and its working fine there but in my application its not working?? Can any one tell me what are possible reasons for that??
here is my code

```
        else if (_db.DbProviderFactory.ToString().Contains("OracleClient"))
        {
            RadDatePicker mtb = new RadDatePicker();
            mtb.ID = "MTB" + _caption.Replace(" ", "_").ToUpper();
            string id="MTB" + _caption.Replace(" ", "_").ToUpper();;
            mtb.EnableViewState = false;
            mtb.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server");
            mtb.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;

            // Both Event
            mtb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "oraProcessDate('" +        "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + mtb.ID + "'," + n + "); return false;");
            mtb.Attributes.Add("onblur", "oraProcessDate('" + "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + mtb.ID + "'," + n + "); return false;");
            mtb.AutoPostBack = true;
            //mtb.SelectedDateChanged += new Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.SelectedDateChangedEventHandler(mtb_SelectedDateChanged);
            mtb.SelectedDateChanged += new Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.SelectedDateChangedEventHandler(pckDate_SelectedDateChanged);
            //rdp.SelectedDateChanged += new SelectedDateChangedEventHandler(rdp_SelectedDateChanged); 
           // mtb.AutoPostBack = true;
            //this.mtb.+= new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(datePicker_SelectedDateChanged);
            //mtb.SelectedDateChanged += new SelectedDateChangedEventHandler(mtb_changed);
            //mtb.SelectedDateChanged+=
            mtb.Width = 200;
            tc.Controls.Add(mtb);
            tc.Style.Add("width", "35%");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            ValidateFields(n, _requirefield.ToString());
            mtb.SelectedDateChanged += new Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.SelectedDateChangedEventHandler(pckDate_SelectedDateChanged);
        }
    }


    protected void pckDate_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.SelectedDateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "testttttttting";

    }
```

Comment: can you show your markup, please?

Comment: Complete Page markup??

Comment: `mtb.SelectedDateChanged += ... ` is added twice. Is it intentional?

Comment: any part that you think might help, also, have you checked for script errors in the console when you change the date? does the datepicker appear correctly on your page?

Comment: Hassan i have also tryd single mtb.SelectedDateChanged += ... it has no affect result is same :(

Comment: Soner Gönül there is no any Script Error :(